# prove that midpoints of DC,AE,BF are collinear

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Question** -

a straight line meets AB,BC and AC produced of ABC at D,E,F respectively.prove that midpoints of DC,AE,BF are collinear....

**My try** -

I suppose that P and Q are midpoints of AE and DC respectively...then I draw lots of parallel lines from them to the sides to use midpoint theorem ...but none of them works.
menelaus didn't work either...

Any hints ??

Comment: Try calculating the areas of triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Newton-Gauss line.  Knowing the name, you can Google for proofs on the web, including [this one at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Gauss_line#Existence_of_the_Newton%E2%88%92Gauss_line).  In case the link goes bad, here's a screen cap.

[image]